# Angular http request retry causes multiple insert

Tags: mysql, angularjs, api, angular-http

I have built an angular app which calls a REST API to insert data into MySQL DB.

The logic is if the app doesn't get response within 10 seconds, it retries the same request.

At the server, there are some logic applied to calculate some values which are required to insert the data. So when the number of insert records passed by the client is more, the request cannot be completed within 10 seconds. The client aborts the request and retries the same. This causes multiple records insert.

Could someone suggest a proven solution for the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, don't retry. What's the point of retrying if you're not getting any error? That will only cause duplicates, and put even more pressure on an already overwhelmed server.

Comment: I have planned to stamp a unique request id to each request to API and at the API end, check if the request was already processed. If yes send an error message saying that duplicate request receive. Is that a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Only do a retry on an error, otherwise you are getting duplicates for responses don't error (eventually giving you a response).